# Dropdown in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I have following ViewModel containing "NumberOfAdults" fields.

```
public class SearchView
{
    public int NumberOfAdults { get; set; }
    // More fields...

}
```

Assuming it will have some value (lets say 5) populated from some configuration file and I have a strongly typed View. What is the best way to populate a dropdown containing text and values of 1,2,3,4,5 without hard coding `<Select...><Option value="1">1</Option></Select>`? Is there a MVC way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if there's a helper that I'm not thinking of that could build the SelectList more elegantly, but this works.

```
    <%  
        // Build a list of SelectListItem from 1 to N
        List<SelectListItem> options = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= Model.NumberOfAdults; i++)
        {
            string stringValue = i.ToString();
            SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Value = stringValue, Text = stringValue };
            options.Add(item);
        }
    %>

    <%= Html.DropDownList("yourName", options) %>
```

This renders:

```
<select id="yourName" name="yourName">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```